# jQuery to ASMX webservice xml transfer

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I need a little help,I googled for hours and I am starting to be a bit desperate.
I need to create asp.net asmx webservice, with method, which will consume data in xml. My problem is, that I dont know how to configure the webservice and the `$.ajax()` Some people told me to encode the xml to string and decode it on the server, but this isn't good solution for me, because the webservice has to be as universal as it is possible. So can anyone give me some simple example of `$.ajax()` call to an asmx webservice transfering for example `<xml attr='test'>test</xml>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the service side:

```
[WebMethod]
public void Foo(string xml)
{
    ... do something with the XML
}
```

and on the client side:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'bar.asmx/foo',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ xml: '<xml attr="test">test</xml>' }),
    success: function(result) {
        alert('The XML was successfully sent to the web service');
    }
});
```

Oh and by the way, ASMX is a very deprecated technology. You should consider using WCF or Web API for developing server side web services on .NET.

Comment: 1) can I use GET here ? 2) must I send json ?

Comment: Wow, thanks for this amazing answer. This helped me solve posting xml in Vue to an old asmx service, which will be upgraded to WebAPI.